# Get the primary key of one table and insert into another table

Tags: sql-server, database

I have 2 tables named `[user]` and `comment`. Now I want to get the primary key of `[user]` and insert that value into the `comment` table without using the `scope_identity`.

Because `scope_identity` retrieves the last primary id only. I want already inserted data primary key of `[user]` table and insert that primary key into `comment` table.

Please anyone help me ....

Comment: Why you need to do it using c#? What other data are you inserting?

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: actually i want to know who is the logged in and comment the post thats why i want to get the primary id from the [user] table and store it into the comment table .

Comment: It might sound a little harsh, but it seems you need help with something else, and your question is waaaay off the mark. First think of a process to save currently logged in user in a session or something, then use that value.

Comment: Please show some example with explain .

Comment: please anyone help me out .

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method:

```
Insert into [User] 
OUTPUT Inserted.Id INTO #InsertedRows
(Col1, Col2, ...)
VALUES (@Col1, @Col2, ...)



INSERT INTO Comment(UserId)
Select Id FROM #InsertedRows
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 INSERT INTO Comment (UserID)
 SELECT UserID FROM [User] WHERE UserID NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM Comment)
```

It will insert all the `UserID`, if it is not found in the `Comment` table